# Node.js start reading a file on a specific line

Tags: javascript, node.js

On Node.js we can read a file line by line using the `readline` module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('filepath');
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log(`Line read: ${line}`);
});
```

But what if we want to start reading on a specific line number? I know that when we use the `createReadStream` we can pass in a `start` parameter. This is explained in the docs:

> `options` can include `start` and `end` values to read a range of bytes from the file instead of the entire file.

But here `start` is one offset in bytes, so it seems complicated to use this to set the starting line.

How can we adapt this approach to start reading a file on a specific line?

Comment: In order to determine where a line break occurs, you need to read the file. There's no way to just open a file and be able to jump to the byte immediately following a `\n`.

Answer (score 7):

You have to read the file from the beginning and count lines and start processing the lines only after you get to a certain line.  There is no way to have the file system tell you where a specific line starts.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var cntr = 0;

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('filepath');
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    if (cntr++ >= 100) {
        // only output lines starting with the 100th line
        console.log(`Line read: ${line}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: indeed, you can specify exact line number by this implementation tho